# Clone OS to another partition as bootable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I want to clone my current Xubuntu partition (and all the personal stuff in it) to another partition on the same drive, make it bootable and then upgrade the OS in the new one.  I like to have several versions available on this machine, and have most (not all) of my user data on other partitions I can mount to whichever one I boot.

I get stuck early in the process.  I assume it's because UUID's are used to specify boot targets, and I don't know all the places I need to change them.  I was just cloning with partclone.ext4, setting a new UUID on the new partition, editing /etc/fstab and doing grub-update.  Now I can no longer boot by selecting my old partition (I get to GRUB rescue, which I don't know how to use), however when I try to boot the new partition it works, but I end up in the old one.  Very clumsy and doesn't do what I want.  I may be wrong about UUIDs, because I can't imagine how it got me in this tangled state.

So is there a way to do this cleanly?

Is there a way to clean up the damage I already did?  Or at least pointers on where to look for the problem.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Grub only boots one install, and then from grub menu you can boot other installs. I like to use Boot-Repair's report to document my system. I can also search for UUIDs, although report does not show full grub.cfg anymore. I also prefer new install to avoid these kinds of issues & restore from backup to make identical, if desired. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report,  use more current ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I have both UEFI and BIOS systems. In my fumbling around with the breakage, I find that Boot-Repair fails on one of my laptops -- the screen is entirely blank, or unreadable, depending on answers I give before it really starts up. Accordingly, I cannot create anything in pastebin. It have just done a fresh install, and all is well, but the question remains: how can I clone a partition and make it bootable? Two answers are okay if UEFI and BIOS are that different

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are that different. And you cannot easily clone a partition because of all the editing of UUIDs, GUIDs & then updating grub. Really a lot easier to do a new install & restore from backup. With BIOS you have only one MBR per drive, and grub from last install will be in control unless you do an install without grub. UEFI use ESP - efi system partition but only one /EFI/ubuntu folder for booting. I have tried creating others, but something is hard coded to only use /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg for booting.